# Get app tabs visibilty for user based on profiles and permission sets

Tags: profile, metadata, permission-sets, tab, app

I have an app and want to know, which fields are visible for a user. I have tried to get [CustomApplication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customapplication.htm?q=navigation%20item) metadata, but it's just list of tabs.

So for example: I have user User1 and App1 with Object1__c, Object2__c, Object3__c. Object1__c, Object2__c have default "on" tab visibility on User1 profile and Object3__c default "off", but is visible via permission set assigned to User1. How can I check that tab visibilities for all App1 tabs?

Also I have tried [PermissionSetTabSetting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_permissionsettabsetting.htm?search_text=ProfileMetadata), but it's too inconvenient for multiple tabs, users and permission sets and doesnt include profile visibility.

Shortly, I want to check if the tabs of an app are visible for a user. Any help will be appreciated. At least I need to know if there is any way to do it.